# how to check for the end of a line in a c char array without a new line at the end

Tags: c

I have a char array that I get from the user and I need to return which is the longest word and which is the shortest, my problem is that my code doesn't recognize the last word because of my if term as it wont enter the else block for the last word because it wont recognize any spaces or new lines and I don't know how to fix it.

```
  while (c != EOF)
  {
    counter++;
    if (c != 32 && c != '\n') {
      lengthCounter++;/*1*/
      charHolder[i] = c;/*m*/
      i++;/*1*/

    } else {

      if (lengthCounter/*1*/>= maxLenght/*3*/) {

        maxLenght = lengthCounter;/*4*/

        for (j = 0; j < lengthCounter + 1; j++) {
          maxWord[j] = charHolder[j];/*cccc*/
        }
        lengthCounter = 0;
      }
      c = getchar();
```

I have tried `c != EOF` at the if statement but that didn't change anything.

One important thing is that I need to "finish" the input from the user with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: If the code doesn't work, include a proper [mcve] that demonstrates that behavior; not partial code. This code is smattered with variables, *none* of which are divulging their types. It's important. Also, the test for EOF should break the loop internally, not as an outer condition, thereby effectively treating the condition as "special" whitespace, that delivers the same behavior as space/newline, but also terminates the loop via break.

Comment: `c != 32` You should not use magic numbers for character constants. If you mean a space, use a space: `c != ' '`.

Comment: Make sure that `c` is declared as `int` and not `char` because EOF is explicitely outside of the `char` range. So `c == EOF` will give the expected result or not depending on the implementation...

Comment: EliKnaffo, `c = getchar();` only occurs when  `if (c != 32 && c != '\n')` is false.   Is that intended?